# Could my ex husband be spying on me through my phone

Tags: iphone

Could my husband be using my phone number and Apple ID

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned that your ex might be looking at your accounts, change all of your passwords, start with your email accounts first.

Comment: One more thing please hes the owner of the account I was wondering if there was a way he could be accessing iCloud??

Comment: @Tia Hobbs RE: " hes the owner of the account" --  He's the owner of what account? As the owner of an account I would suspect he has access to anything associated with the account.  Get your own account and stop using anything associated with his account!

Comment: @TiaHobbs Create and switch to your own Apple ID *first*, before changing any other passwords -- otherwise, he might get any other new passwords you set via iCloud Keychain synchronization. Actually, even before doing that I'd be tempted to start by making a backup of your phone (to iTunes on a Mac or PC, *not* to iCloud 'cause he owns that). Also, be aware that you may need to re-purchase apps that're "owned" by his Apple ID.